# How is `last` allowed to be called for an Args value?

Tags: rust, traits

Here is a small Rust script (yes, I know `unwrap` is discouraged but it works for this short example):

```
fn main() {
    let args = std::env::args();
    let word = args.last().unwrap();
    println!("Last argument is {}", word);
}
```

I see from the Rust documentation that

- [`std`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/) is a crate
- [`env`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/) is a module within crate `std`
- [`args`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html) is a function within the module
- The function returns a value of type [`Args`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Args.html), a struct
- The struct `Args` implements the traits [`Iterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) and [`ExactSizeIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html)

However, neither `Args` nor `Iterator` nor `ExactSizeIterator`, as far as I can tell from the documentation, ever defines a method called `last`! `Args` defines  nothing on its own, `Iterator` just defines `next` and `size_hint`, and `ExactSizeIterator` defines `len`.

So why does this script work? How is `last` allowed to be called for an `Args` value? Is the documentation lacking or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `last` method comes from the [`IteratorExt`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html) trait, which defines methods for all iterators by having a `impl<I> IteratorExt for I where I: Iterator` blanket implementation.

These methods are in scope, because the trait `IteratorExt` is imported in the [`prelude`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/v1/).

Comment: Ah, the prelude - that's the reason I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to work both directions in the documentation. Doing a search for `last` will lead you to [`IteratorExt::last`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.last):

```
fn last(self) -> Option<<Self as Iterator>::Item>
```

`IteratorExt` is defined as:

```
pub trait IteratorExt where Self: Iterator {
    // ...
}
```

This is an *extension trait* - a collection of methods that are all applied to another trait. It's done this way to help preserve *object safety*, as some of these methods require consuming the argument, which means that the argument has to have a known size. The trait has a *blanket implementation* to get it to apply:

```
impl<I> IteratorExt for I where I: Iterator
```

However, there's been some [work recently](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23104) to reduce the number of extension traits, as it was realized that you can simply add a bound of `Sized` to certain methods. It's possible some of that might apply to `IteratorExt` and they will move back to `Iterator` proper.

Comment: Ah, I had stumbled across `core::slice::SliceExt::last` but did not see how slices had anything to do with iterators. I since noticed the search button on top of the reference pages and now see there are many `last`s. Nice link to the PR on reducing the number of extension traits.

Comment: @RayToal careful - [`core::SliceExt::last`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/slice/trait.SliceExt.html#tymethod.last) and [`std::IteratorExt::last`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.last) have the same name and similar concepts, but are different! In fact, `SliceExt::last` has been moved to an *inherent implementation* on `[T]`. Unfortunately, that [isn't currently available in the documentation!](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23511).